# Adding values of multiple text box values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple text boxes with a class name `.paymentamount`.i want to add all values of text boxes of the same class but i am getting error nan.Code is this

```
function paymentData()
{
    $('.paymentamount').keyup(function(){
        var amountSum=0;
        $('.paymentamount').each(function(){
            amountSum+=parseInt(this.value);
        //console.log(this.value);
        });
        console.log(amountSum);

        });
}
```

Comment: suggest modifying `amountSum+=parseInt(this.value);`
as `amountSum+=parseInt($(this).val());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/MaK2k/1/ **or** using `$.isNumeric` http://jsfiddle.net/AKnvr/

```
**Code**


$('.paymentamount').keyup(function(){
   var amountSum=0;
    $('.paymentamount').each(function(){
        if (this.value != "")
           amountSum+=parseInt(this.value);

    });

    $(".paymentamountlable").text(amountSum);


    });
```

​

Comment: No probs, @Hira - Glad it helped you can use; extra `.isNumeric` and `isNan` if you want to make sure that it only sum up the numeric values! :) Another demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/AKnvr/

Answer (score 2):

```
   1. $.trim($(this).val())
   2. make use of $(this).val()
   3. check before adding var match = /^[0-9]$/.test(value);
```

Final code for you after this modification to your code

```
 $('.paymentamount').each(function(){
           var value = $.trim($(this).val()); 
           var match = /^[0-9]$/.test(value); 
           if(match)
             amountSum+=parseInt(value);
         //console.log(this.value);
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function paymentData()
{
    $('.paymentamount').keyup(function(){
        var amountSum=0;
        $('.paymentamount').each(function(){
            amountSum+=parseFloat($.trim($(this).val()));

        });
        console.log(amountSum);

        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.paymentamount').keyup(function(){
    var amountSum=0;
    $('.paymentamount').each(function(){
        if(parseInt(this.value) > 0)
        {
        amountSum = parseInt(this.value) + parseInt(amountSum);
        }
    }); 

 console.log(amountSum);
});



Try this
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try:

```
amountSum+=parseInt($(this).val());
```

Comment: -1 because `parseInt()` can return `NaN` if the value is not numeric, and also because you missed the radix argument for `parseInt()`. This argument is optional, but should be specified, because otherwise it can default to octal, which can give some unexpected results.